# How to implement image mask?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

Situtation:

I am working on a small application which should enable user to trigger something depending on which part of the screen they clicked. Imagine a picture of a teddy bear and if you click a nose it says "nose". What I have done is put in layout xml a LinearLayout. Because I have to cover different screen sizes I didn't set background in a xml layout file.

snippet form xml:

```
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/viewMain"            
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:visibility="visible" >    
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewThouShaltRespondToClicks"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

  <!-- mask -->
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewInvisibleMask"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And then in onCreate event of activity I check the display resolution and via setBackgroundResource() set the appropriate background. I have prepared background images for each resolution.

```
final Point QVGA = new Point(240,320);  // portrait
// Obtain the screen resolution if the device
Display defaultDisplay = ((WindowManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
Point displayResolution = new Point(defaultDisplay.getWidth(), defaultDisplay.getHeight());
if (displayResolution.equals(QVGA))
        {
           viewThouShaltRespondToClicks.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_to_be_clicked_upon_240x320);
viewInvisibleMask.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mask_240x320);

       }
else if ... // check for another resolution
```

Even if the image in the resources is not in the correct dimension it is stretched/shrinked to the screen size. This would be OK as long as the width-height ratio of background image is similar to ratio of display and the resulting image is not kewed to much. But there is a problem, explained below.

To detect which region was clicked, the region itself might be irregular shaped I have taken the following approach. I create an image – mask (bmp) with same dimensions as background image only that it has a white background and the clickable areas are in different colors. The color identifies the area. All I have to is get a coordinate of a click event (no problem here), go to the mask image and read the color of pixel on this coordinates. The problem is that the mask image is not of the correct size. On my device it is set to 1200x700, but I guess it takes on some arbitrary size on other devices.

First question: Is there a way to somehow convince the invisible layout to load background image and then stretch/shrink it to display size as it happens for visible layout by itself?

Another approach would be to load mask image (bmp, png) into some memory structure and resize it to display size. 
I have tried with something like:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;   // do not scale
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
bitmapMask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.mask, options);
// on this place stretch shrink should follow but I have no idea how
```

But I don’t know how to scale Bitmap to proper size.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First question: yes, you can have a separate View in your layout containing the mask image, and set it to be invisible with `android:visibility=invisible`.

Second question: you can read a pixel value from the bitmap with `Bitmap.getPixel()`. [Docs are here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: Attentive reader would notice that I already made a mask view invisible. problem is that the background image assumes some arbitrary size (1200x700 in my case), which does not correspond to the actual view size.
And getPixel() method is also known to me. The problem is, that I don't know how to scale bitmap to proper size.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple suggestion. You could have the reference image in an imageview behind the real image. So both images are loaded in the exact same way, placed in ImageViews, and then inserted into a relativelayout. That way they should be equal size, and only one of them is visible.

This might not be a very pretty way of doing it, and i'm not sure if it will work, but you can try it out.

Comment: I am not sure if I get what you mean. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: You create a RelativeLayout, to contain the original image AND the image with the touch colors. A RelativeLayout allows views to be on top of each other. So you let the touch-color image be behind the original one. The ImageViews that contain the images, should have the exact same properties. This way, the images will be scaled exactly the same (If the images you load are the same size). Then you should be able to map the touch on the original image, to the colors on the image behind it.